# How can I run Xcode 7 beta 5 on OS X 10.10.3?

Tags: xcode, xcode7-beta5

I have [downloaded](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/) Xcode 7 beta 5 and was trying to install it on Mac 10.10.3. This is the error message I got:

> You can’t use this version of the application “Xcode-beta.app” with this version of OS X.
>
> You have OS X 10.10.3. The application requires OS X 10.10.4 or later.

In [Xcode Release notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7_beta_5/Xcode_7_beta_5_Release_Notes.pdf) it is said that OS X 10.10.3 **is** supported.

> Xcode 7 beta 5 requires a Mac running OS X 10.10.3 or later.

How can I get Xcode beta 5 run on 10.10.3?

Comment: Easiest solution: update to OS X 10.10.4.

Comment: No problem - comment now converted to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest solution is jut to go to the OS X App Store, select the Updates tab, and then update your OS to 10.10.4.

Comment: When the problem is how to run it on 10.10.3, updating to 10.10.4 isn't a solution. But it does seem there is no way around it.